# How to automatic number from another workbook at a click of a button?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, save

I have a case where a bunch of seven excel sheets (each sheet is a separate report) in a common folder should get report numbers every time I create a new sheet or copy an existing sheet in any of the seven files. I've copy and create buttons on all sheets. I'm a novice with vba.

I wish to do the following by clicking on a vba button in Report.xlsm:

```
1) Open 'Count.xlsx' and read the number in cell A1.
2) Store that number to a temp variable.
3) Increment A1 in Count.xlsx by one.
4) Save and close Count.xlsx.
5) Come back to Report.xlsm
6) Create a new sheet from a template (Sheet name = Master)
7) Paste the number in the temp variable to a cell in the newly created sheet.
```

Here's what I managed to type:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim ShName As String
Dim ShNum As String
Dim Counter As String
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Count.xlsx"
With Worksheets("Counter")
ShNum = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
Counter = ShNum
ShNum = ShNum + 1
ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = ShNum
End With
Workbooks("Count.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ReportFile.xlsm"
With Worksheets("Master")
ShName = Year(Date) & " " & Counter
.Copy After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
Range("B6").Value = Date
End With
Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = ShName
End Sub
```

Could someone let me understand where I am going wrong? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really mention what the problem is you're having, but try this:

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim ShName As String
    Dim ShNum As String
    Dim Counter As Long, wb As Workbook
    
    Counter = NextNumber()
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ReportFile.xlsm")
    wb.Worksheets("Master").Copy after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
    With wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
        .Name = Year(Date) & " " & Counter
        .Range("B6").Value = Date
    End With
   
End Sub

'get current number and increment
Function NextNumber() As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Count.xlsx")
    With wb.Worksheets("Counter").Range("A1")
        NextNumber = .Value 'return the current value
        .Value = .Value + 1 'next number
    End With
    wb.Close savechanges:=True
End Function
```

When opening a workbook it's a good idea to assign it directly to a variable so you're not working with ActiveWorkbook/ActiveSheet etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. The problem that I was having was that the file from which this code was executed, Reportfile.xlsm was forced to be reopened after each iteration (as is obviously seen from the code). Is there a way to read/write from count.xlsx without opening the file? Like...silently update the values and save the file?

Comment: Do you have multiple users ?  Is file locking a problem?  If you just don't like seeing then file open and close then you can add `Application.Screenupdating = False` to the `NextNumber` function.